# Connect Microsoft bot framework node js v4 bot to IBM DB2 database

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I have a Microsoft bot v4 in node js. I would like to connect this bot to the DB2 database of my organization to pull certain data.

could you please help how can I achieve this.

I look for your help/suggestions.

Comment: Can you clarify...you want to use that DB for Bot State Storage, or for some kind of custom storage?

Answer (score 0):

The Bot Framework v4 dosen't have the DB2 connection library. So, you need to use the [node-ibm_db driver](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.javascript.doc/doc/t0061585.html) support from IBM. Bot apps will be able to use it as well as general Node.js apps.